# Multiple tables with JOINS

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, in `table1` I have columns `user_d` and `user_i`, the next code, return only name for `user_d`.

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.name as nameuser  FROM table1 INNER JOIN
table2 ON table1.user_d=table2.id  where table1.id=1
```

How to return username for table1 `user_i` column too?

Comment: what is app_utilizatori?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct(tickets.id),(select name from users where user_d=id) as user_d,
(select name from users where user_i=id) as user_i from tickets  INNER JOIN
users ON tickets.user_d=users.id order by tickets.id asc
```

Comment: not working, on are only for user_d, and how to make ford user_i too?

Comment: show full table structure for table1 and table2 with some values .

Comment: i have posted and answer with structure.

Comment: Table 1 USER_I column empty ?

Comment: user_D and user_I is id's from Table2-USERS, is who open the ticket and who close the ticket. i need to know the names for each, to show name for one column it's simple i make a INNER JOIN table2 on table1.user_d=table2.id. But how to make for user_i too? i try with INNER JOIN ON.... OR... but not working